# Sharepoint - InfoPath URL to database SQL query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath, sql-query, infopath-form

We have old Sharepoint (2010) website.

The sharepoint form can be accessed with URL in the below format /_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/abc/def/20150401t092014.xml

For some reason it just times out. How can I translate that to SQL query to get actual XML from database. Will it be in WSS_Content database ?

EDIT : I think I am able to filter entries in AllDocs table based on DirName is there any way to get full form info based on Ids in AllDocs table ?

Comment: Just a friendly reminder it's against unsupported to read content databases directly through SQL.